# Using ObserverPattern, but need to stop some observers displaying changes immediately

Tags: gui, observer-pattern

In a GUI application (to organize images), I use the Observer Pattern (or anything similar to model-view-(view)controller) to inform other components about changes.

Assuming three components A, B, C which show different aspects of some objects, I can trigger "batch actions" which affect many objects in A and B. Each change will lead to an update of the set of objects in any or all of A, B, C, depending on the change.

If A now triggers a change of three objects, B and C will display three successive changes each. Apart from taking time, it's flickering the UI.

What I would need is some way of globally (argh!) saying that during the batch action, no UI changes should happen. Since I would not want to limit the usage of the ObserverPattern to UI stuff, I would like to not stop the entire pattern from working, but only the UI-relevant part of it.

Any idea? When I came across this situation, I was thinking it's a usual requirement, and I wondered why I haven't come across a solution before.

Comment: How much time do those batch operations take? Would it be an option to put a small delay between receiving the update and actually redrawing the UI (with updates being received during the delay being merged)?

Answer (score 4):

You may be interested in using something like [Reactive Extensions](http://reactivex.io/) to do some more complex event processing.

Specifically, using the [Sample Filter](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/sample.html) might be just want you want here.

If you combine all your events that result in a UI refresh into a single stream and **sample** that stream then you can avoid unnecessary UI refreshes.

Comment: "Observer pattern done right" -  cool! Starred the RxPy repository and will look into it. Since you stress the sampling, I started to wonder whether I can really drop some events and still the internal state is consistent.

Comment: FYI, Your links appeared to have titles appended to the end, which was breaking them for me. ... I stripped those off, hopefully still linking to the desired pages...

Comment: Cool, thanks.  I'm still a bit iffy on the URL markup/down.  I probably got it wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few strategies I'd consider:

- **Refresh on an interval.**
   Pick an interval based on the *longest* you'd want to wait to see an update and the *longest* time you might be waiting between notifications. Either queue the notifications and handle them *and* the UI update on an interval, or more simply, handle notifications as they arrive and simply refresh the UI on an interval.
- **Pass `batch` objects through the notifications.**
   Include a list of objects that are part of the batch, an `ObjectsCount`, or a `BatchCompleted` state. Whatever's easiest for you to include and/or interpret.
- **Put every change in a `Batch` and watch a `BatchJobs` channel/object.**
   Your `Batch` can include a collection of changes or changed objects. You can either delay it's insertion into the channel until it's complete, or include an `IsComplete` status and make it observable (or just include an `OnComplete` event).

Answer (score 0):

You should introduce an intermediate level between the Observed and the Observers. Instead of having Y Observe Z directly (Y<-Z), have Y observing X which observes Z  (Y<-X<-Z) . When X is notified of the event of Z, it can delay publishing its own event to Y until you are ready.

Comment: I wouldn't like to do this literally, since the observer often wants to know which observable triggered the event. But your idea made me think whether I could add some more generic stuff into the ObserverPattern which would allow to stop some events...

Comment: That's cool. Whatever works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I finally ended up with: My [PausableObserverPattern](https://github.com/virtualnobi/PausableObserverPattern) on Github. Comments welcome!

The Reactive Extensions mentioned by @MetaFight seemed to be too big (i.e., too complex) to me.

Refreshing on an interval does not work since I do not know how long the batch process will need.

Since I am using a very simple ObserverPattern (see github), there's no easy way to pass additional data about the batch of changes.

The answer by @user889742 triggered my thinking - only the "intermediate" level he mentions is the Observable class (actually a subclass).